# Ruby on Rails: extract the file from db, analyze it, results save in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [this file upload example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) to upload some files in the database. I have a rruby.rb with r-script in it which makes statistical analysis of the file(name it A) , and as a result it saves  a plot in the directory where the file A is situated.
What I need is to extract the file from the database, do analysis and save the plot back into a database.
 Where should I place the code of rruby.rb?In [uploads_controller](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example/blob/master/app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb), [upload.rb](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example/blob/master/app/models/upload.rb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the `rruby.rb` file separate and use it as is. But where to place that file?

There are two equally valid options. Either you place it in `lib` folder, or place it in the `models` folder.

I would place it in the `lib` folder if I consider more generic and code that I happen to need. Code in `lib` is code that eventually could be turned into a gem. It is code that I consider completely unrelated to any business code or models.

If the code is strongly related to my business domain and other models.

So in your case I would place the `rruby` file in the `lib` folder since (if I understand correctly) it contains an pretty isolated procedure, no dependency on the rest of the code, just needs a file as input, and will generate a file as output.

Another advantage of keeping `rruby` code separate is that you can test it in isolation as well.

Hope this helps.

[EDIT: added example implementation]

I presume your `rruby` is a simple script, so you wrap it in a module, since it performs statistical analysis I call it `Statistical`, but you should give it a more appropriate name

So in `lib/statistical.rb` write

```
module Statistical

  def self.do_analysis(file_to_analyse)
    # .. do a lot of stuff and return a result-file
  end
end
```

Then in your uploadscontroller or uploads model, you do something like

```
result_file = Statistical.do_analysis(uploaded_file)
```

Normally all files inside the `lib` are automatically added to rails load-path, so this is all you need to do.

Comment: Ok. I place it then separatelz in a lib folder. How can I call it from there? And should I call it then from my uploads_controller.rb when a new Upload is creating ( The analysis should be there as soon as the file is uploaded)? How can I call a rruby.rb from a lib folder in uploads_controller.rb?

Comment: Yep. It is perfect, but i still have one small question.It is the simpliest version of my rruby.r .

    require "rinruby"
    R.quit
    myr = RinRuby.new(echo=false)
    myr.filename = "myplot"myr.eval <<EOF
png(filename)
    plot(1:10)
    rect(1, 5, 3, 7, col="white")

  
  dev.off()
    EOF

It produces a plot somewhere in the direcory where you call a plot. I have not found how I can specify a plot to a variable or how can I upload a code to a database

Comment: So, actually a r-script doesnt return a file, it poduces a plot that is saved somewhere(while running rruby.rb in a command line). As soon as I type everything in ruby on rails upload project, I have no idea where it will save a plot and how can I save this plot in a database.

Comment: I see you are rinruby, maybe https://github.com/jtprince/rserve-simpler is more interesting: i see in the docs they can generate plots to file.  Does that help?

Comment: I hope. If it doesnt work or I have questions, I will post them here. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess rserve-simpler ist the same as rinrubz in terms of saving a file. They botj create a file somewhere. I do not know how it should work in the Ruby on Rails database.

Comment: I have posted result_file=Statistical.do.. in my uploads_controller.rb It tells me Statistical is an uninitialized constant

Comment: Look for `load_path` in `config/application.rb`, might need to add `lib` there. E.g. like this: `config.autoload_paths += %W({config.root}/lib)`. With regards to R I am afraid I can't really help you.

Comment: Ok. I will try this out. Do you have any idea bout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443014/ruby-on-railssearch-for-a-word-in-a-file-before-uploading ? I am not that good in RoR. Thanks  for your time

Comment: I am so sorry, but you are so good in RoR. Maybe you can have an idea how to fix this thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531167/ruby-on-rails-error-in-opening-database-file-in-r  Thanks-)

Comment: Flattery always helps, of course :) But I am also glad to be able to help, and hopefully you can start to enjoy ruby on rails.