# Ruby on Rails: save R plot in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, r

I am using [this file upload example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) to upload some files in the database. I have a rruby.rb with r-script in it which makes statistical analysis of the file(name it A) , and as a result it saves a plot in the directory where the file A is situated(or anywhere else).
What I need is to save the plot-file back into a database.

It is the simpliest version of my rruby.r .

```
require "rinruby" 
R.quit myr = RinRuby.new(echo=false) 
myr.filename = "myplot"myr.eval <<EOF 
 png(filename) 
 plot(1:10) 
 rect(1, 5, 3, 7, col="white") 
 dev.off() 
EOF
```

How will it work in Ruby on Rails? I was suggested to construct the rruby.rb [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422742/ruby-on-rails-extract-the-file-from-db-analyze-it-results-save-in-the-db). Will it save the file into public/system (where the uploads files are situated)? How can I save a file within Ruby on Rails database?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked two extremely different questions.

On the one side, you're talking about trying to dump R-generated charts into a folder while using the rinruby gem. This is what I'm working on. Good question.

On the other side, you're asking us how to store "images in a database". Try to take things one at a time. Remove part 2 of your question. Have you figured out task 1? I haven't.

PS: There is no such thing as a "ruby on rails database".