# Ruby on Rails:search for a word in a file before uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [this example for file uploader.](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)
Before uploading a file I would like to open it, search for a specific word, assign this word to an attribute in the database and only then save the file in the database.

Example:

I select two files and click "upload".
The file name is assigned to a upload_file_name. 
File's size is assigned to an upload_file_size.
File is opened, I search for a word "Bug" or "Lion". 
If i find "Lion", "Lion" should be assigned to an upload_content_type. If I find "Bug", "Bug" should be assigned to upload_content_type.

I am not quite sure where I have to define the function that will open a file: in [uploads_controller.rb](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example/blob/master/app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb) or in [uploads.rb](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example/blob/master/app/models/upload.rb)? And I do not know how to assign a "Bug" to an upload_content_type.

That is my upload.rb:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :upload, :upload_file_name, :upload_file_size

Paperclip::interpolates :piks do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.upload_file_name
end
  has_attached_file :upload,

                    :url =>"/system/Files/Files/:piks/:basename.:extension",
                    :path =>":rails_root/public/system/Files/Files/:piks/:basename.:extension"

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

   validates :upload_file_name,  :presence   => true,
                                :format     =>{:with => %r{\.(txt)$}i,:message =>"should have an extension .cell"}

  validates_uniqueness_of :upload_file_name, :message =>"exists already."     

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => (read_attribute(:upload_file_name)).split(".").first,
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
```

my uploads_controller.rb:

```
def create
    p_attr=params[:upload]
    p_attr[:upload] = params[:upload][:upload].first if params[:upload][:upload].class == Array
    @upload = Upload.new(p_attr)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json,
          :content_type => 'BUUUUU',
          :layout => false
        }

        format.json { render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }        

        format.json{ render json: {name:(@upload.upload_file_name).split(".").first ,error: @upload.errors.messages[:upload_file_name]}, :status =>422}

      end
    end
  end
```

Database:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120731045929) do

  create_table "uploads", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "upload_file_name"
    t.string   "upload_content_type"
    t.string   "user"
    t.integer  "upload_file_size"
    t.datetime "upload_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  end

end
```

And function to open a file:

```
def check
    File.open(??filename) do |file|
        file.each do |line|     
         type=/Lion/.match(line)       
         if type != nil 
            puts(type[0])   #assign to a database!!
            break
         end

        end
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Upload` model you could add the following:

```
class Upload

  before_save :determine_content_type


  def determine_content_type
    file_contents = File.readlines(upload.queued_for_write[:original].path).join('\n')
    self.content_type = if file_contents.include?('Bug')
                          'Bug'
                        else if file_contents.include?('Lion')
                          'Lion'
                        else
                          'Unknown'
                        end
  end  
end
```

Short explanation:

- assign a `before_save` callback in the model, that will check the file and determine the content type
- check PaperClip documentation: the attachment before saving can be found in the `queued_for_write` hash
- load that file, read all the lines and concatenate in a single string
- check if the string contains 'Bug' or 'Lion'
- assign the value to the `content_type` column, because this is called before saving, it will be saved correctly

> Note: when updating the record this will also trigger the `before_save` callback, if this is not what you want (you can't edit or replace the uploaded file), you better use the `before_create` callback.

Hope this helps.