# Ruby on Rails, error in opening database file in R

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [this example for file uploader.](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)
After saving the file, I want to analyze it with R and save the r-plot in the database.

That is my upload.rb:

```
Paperclip::interpolates :array_type_folder do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.upload_content_type
end
  has_attached_file :upload,
                    
                    :url =>"/system/Files/:array_type_folder/:basename.:extension",
                    :path =>":rails_root/public/system/Files/:array_type_folder/:basename.:extension"

  after_save :do_picture_analyse
def do_picture_analyse
   require 'rinruby'
    myr = RinRuby.new(echo=false)      
    myr.fileurl=upload.url(:original)
    puts "#{myr.fileurl}"
    myr.eval <<EOF
       s=read.table(fileurl)
       jpeg(filename=':rails_root/public/system/Files/Pictures/probe.jpeg',width=250, height=250)
       hist(s$V1) 
       dev.off()
   
    EOF
end
```

Due to this line I can see the url of the file in the database(it is just for me to test)

```
 myr.fileurl=upload.url(:original)
    puts "#{myr.fileurl}"
```

This kind of error I get when I upload the file probe2.cel and to analyse it with R:

```
/system/Files/11/probe2.cel?1353680334 (that is the result of puts "#{myr.fileurl}") 
Error in file(file, "rt") : could not open the connection
Error:
In file(file, "rt") :
   '/system/Files/11/probe2.cel?1353680334' no such file or directory
Error in hist(s$V1) : Object 's' not found
```

It seems that it cannot connect to the database and it cannot find the file. How can I handle it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error you get is that the connection to the file could not be made (not sure because it is R).

I see two possible causes:

- the file can't be opened: I think `url` is wrong here, you should use the file-path
- the file can't be saved: I am not sure about the file-syntax you are using in the `jpeg(filename='...')`

So if you would write

```
myr.fileurl = upload.path
myr.new_filepath = "#{Rails.root}/public/system/Files/Pictures/probe.jpeg"

myr.eval <<EOF
   s=read.table(fileurl)
   jpeg(filename=new_filepath, width=250, height=250)
   hist(s$V1) 
   dev.off()
EOF
```

Does that work?

Hope this helps.

Comment: hah. You should get a co-author status in my project-))) Thanks a lot-)

Comment: Is it possible as well to save a new_filepath (so, the path of the plot) in the database column? I have generated a migration of a new column pic. And in the def do_picture_analyse I want to do something like this: self.chip_image='/system/Files/CEL-Files/11/probe2.jpeg' But it seems not to work as always-)

Comment: Remember you are in the `after_save`, so the object has already been saved. Setting an attribute will not save it. Two options: do `update_attribute :chip_image, "..."` (this will not trigger any callback), or set the path in the `before_save`. HTH.

Comment: maybe you know again how to solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659840/ruby-on-rails-connect-a-function-with-the-bootstrap-botton 
thanks-)